# Determine TLS certificate details with Microsoft Edge

Tags: windows-10, proxy, ssl, microsoft-edge

I purchased a new ASUS Q302 laptop from Best Buys for testing some software under the Intel Broadwell architecture ([6th Gen i7](https://superuser.com/q/999515)). It looks like the machine has one of those Proxy/Interception certificates pre-installed. The machine does not appear to have anti-virus software installed, and I did not install any software.

I did not agree to be proxied or intercepted, so I'm not sure what package is doing it. I'm attempting to determine what software package owns it, but I can't get Microsoft Edge to give me the details on the certificate or the fake CA (below, I clicked on the red shield).

[image]

Edge also appears to lack other useful setting provided by Explorer, like a way to manage startup, a ways to reset the browser, and a way to manage browser helper object (BHO).

How, exactly, do I get the new-and-improved Internet Explorer to give me the basic information it used to provide?

---

***Mozilla***

[image]

***Google***

[image]

Comment: Verify IE behaves the same way.  What security software do you have installed and do you have the web protection enabled?

Comment: Is your system’s clock/date/time correct?

Answer (score 6):

There currently isn't a way to view the certificate information from within Microsoft Edge.  You can use Internet Explorer 11 to view the information though.

Alex Mia, a Microsoft Contingent Staff, on September 09, 2015 9:05 AM said the following:

> Hi,
>
> So far, there is no way to view the certificates in the Microsoft Edge
>   browser.

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18301fff-0467-4e41-8dee-4e44823ed5bf/microsoft-edge-browser-and-ssl-certificates?forum=win10itprogeneral)

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Ramhound is accurate. The path to view de Certificate details in newer IE (11) as for Win10 is right-clicking anyplace on the SSL secured page, then >> properties >> certificates >> view certificate; there you go; As for today Microsoft really confirms there isn´t so far a method to do so in Edge;

If in Google-Chrome(v.60.x), click the 3 vertical diposed icon on the top-right > more tools > developer tools > and on the frame exposed with "elements, Console, Source, etc.." browse on the ">>" icon to reach "security", then you will get the "view certificate" icon to perform you checks;

If in Firefox (v.54.0.x) the SSL site will generate a green lock just before the link you´re in, then left-click the lock icon > the site name will appear and then a ">" icon that will lead you to the certificate details;